# How to create a AVI movie in Java?

Tags: java, media, avi

[image: AVI]

I have been working on creating a prototype for screen recorder. So far I have created the GUI. Still a lot of things remain.
One of the main thing is to create an AVI movie from a set of `BufferedImage`.
I tried understanding Monte Media Library but it went way over my head. Is that guy trying to encode things himself? I don't know! :/

So, what is the other way to create an AVI from BufferedImages (or any other suitable means that is out of my limited knowledge) ?

Comment: what do you mean by `avi`? `avi` is just a container format. Do you want to display a video using a set of image?

Comment: @UmNyobe I thought `RIFF` was the container and AVI was a solid file format....I am not sure where I am heading and that's why I created the image to clearly show what is in my head :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How do I create a movie from an array of images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856757/java-how-do-i-create-a-movie-from-an-array-of-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find a pure-java library for that.
Take a look at [gstreamer-java](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/) to see if it fits your needs. Make sure you install the right plugins.

Comment: [SimplePipeline](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/SimplePipelineTutorial) and [VideoTest](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/VideoTestTutorial) will be all I need to learn? *+1 for the help*

Comment: Not sure if you will need more. Good luck

Comment: I still don't know what the source for input is. What is it? Bytes? BufferedImages? Can you help me with it, please ?

Comment: You need to learn gstreamer itself first. It has a complex model of sources and sinks or something like that. Take a look at http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/